# JPA/Hibernate : Foreign key not setted in child entity in bidirectional relationship

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

i have a method that receive an object like this that i want to persist :

```
  "id" : 1121,
  "azienda" : "con inizio validità <= a oggi  senza fine validità mod",
  "codiceLettera" : "con inizio validità <= a oggi  senza fine validità mod",
  "inizioValidita" : 1672873200000,
  "fineValidita" : 1672873200000,
  "nomeDizionario" : "con inizio validità <= a oggi  senza fine validità mod",
  "nomeTemplate" : "con inizio v <= a oggi  senza fine validitÃ   senza allegato",
  "tipoCliente" : "con inizio validità <= a oggi  senza fine validità mod",
  "tipoPagamento" : "con inizio validità <= a oggi  senza fine validità mod",
  "campi" : [ {
    "id" : 1,
    "valoreDefault" : " campo con inizio validità <= a oggi  senza fine validità e senza allegato mod",
    "fileContent" : null,
    "inizioValidita" : 1672873200000,
    "fineValidita" : 1672873200000,
    "nomeCampo" : " campo con inizio validità <= a oggi  senza fine validità e senza allegato mod",
    "nomeTracciato" : " campo con inizio validità <= a oggi  senza fine validità e senza allegato mod",
    "tipoCampo" : "TXT",
    "dizionarioId" : 1121,
    "regolaId" : 2
  } ]
}
```

the "external json refer to an entity called DizionarioEntity :

```
@Table(name = "CFG_T_P8DW0_DIZIONARIO", schema = "P8DW_OWN")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class DizionarioEntity implements Serializable {
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1052202667620987669L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_P8DW0_PDFTEMPLATE")
    //@SequenceGenerator(name = "P8DW_OWN", allocationSize = 1, schema = "P8DW_OWN") 
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_P8DW0_PDFTEMPLATE", allocationSize = 1, schema = "P8DW_OWN")
    @Column(name = "DIZIONARIO_ID", nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = true)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="AZIENDA")
    private String azienda;
    @Column(name="CODICE_LETTERA")
    private String codiceLettera;
    @Column(name = "INIZIO_VALIDITA")
    private Date inizioValidita;
    @Column(name = "FINE_VALIDITA")
    private Date fineValidita;
    @Column(name="NOME_DIZIONARIO")
    private String nomeDizionario;
    @Column(name="NOME_TEMPLATE")
    private String nomeTemplate;
    @Column(name="TIPO_CLIENTE")
    private String tipoCliente;
    @Column(name="TIPO_PAGAMENTO")
    private String tipoPagamento;
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dizionario",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<CampoDizionarioEntity> campi;

}
```

and the internal json attribute  "campi" refer to RegolaCampoDizionarioEntity :

```
@Table(name = "CFG_T_P8DW0_CAMPO_DIZIONARIO", schema = "P8DW_OWN")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class CampoDizionarioEntity implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7526175419939594746L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_P8DW0_PDFTEMPLATE")
    //@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_P8DW0_PDFTEMPLATE", allocationSize = 1, schema = "P8DW_OWN")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_P8DW0_PDFTEMPLATE", allocationSize = 1, schema = "P8DW_OWN")
    @Column(name = "CAMPO_ID", nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "VALORE_DEFAULT")
    private String valoreDefault;
    @Column(name="FILECONTENT")
    private String fileContent;
    @Column(name = "INIZIO_VALIDITA")
    private Date inizioValidita;
    @Column(name = "FINE_VALIDITA", nullable = false)
    private Date fineValidita;
    @Column(name = "NOME_CAMPO")
    private String nomeCampo;
    @Column(name="NOME_TRACCIATO")
    private String nomeTracciato;
    @Column(name="TIPO_CAMPO")
    private String tipoCampo;
    @Column(name="DIZIONARIO_ID")
    private Long dizionarioId;
    @Column(name="REGOLA_ID")
    private Long regolaId;
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_T_P8DW0_DIZIONARIO"), name = "DIZIONARIO_ID",insertable = false , updatable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private DizionarioEntity dizionario;
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_T_P8DW0_REGOLA_CAMPO_DIZIONARIO"), name = "REGOLA_ID", nullable = true,insertable = false , updatable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private RegolaCampoDizionarioEntity regola;
    
    
    

}
```

as you can see there is a bidirectional relationship between the two entities, my question is, how do we make sure that when I save the entity DizionarioEntity with its children CampoDizionarioEntity, the field "DICTIONARY_ID" which is foreign key has as value the value of the relative parent's primary key?

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that column "DICTIONARY_ID" will be correctly set, just make sure that the field `regola` is set with the `DizionarioEntity` on each child.